# exporting texture from blender to cheetah 3d?

Tags: blender, cheetah

i would like to export a texture from blender software to cheetah 3d software. Anyone knows a way to do it ? for now the only way i found it is to export complete model on .obj

Comment: Please see the posting guidelines for Stack Overflow and include some code that you've tried and errors/issues you're having. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, just trying to give pointers so you don't get downvoted quickly.